# Continue process after user has allowed sharing and location found

Tags: ios, asynchronous, cllocationmanager

I have something like this:

```
CLLocationManager *locManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locManager.delegate = self;
locManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

But I need to get below the latitude and longitude user. Obviously, trying to obtain **locManager.coordinate** just below the **startUpdatingLocation** my application crashes.

How can I make a condition to perform a process after the user allows sharing of location and it has been found?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling `startUpdatingLocation` it can take some time until you get a location. The system first checks if location services are enabled for the app and asks the user to allow location services. The GPS hardware first needs to be turned on. It takes some time until it can fix the position.

So you should update the UI to show the user that there is something going on in the background. Consider using a `UIActivityIndicatorView` and maybe set `userInteractionEnabled` of the view to NO. Also it is a good practice to give the user the option to cancel the operation.

In your delegate you must implement these 2 methods:

```
– locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:
– locationManager:didFailWithError:
```

Here you can remove the `UIActivityIndicatorView` and reenable user interaction.
In case of success you can use the coordinate of the `CLLocationManager` to do whatever you want. In case of failure show an error alert.

Call `stopUpdatingLocation` when you don't need location services anymore to save battery.